# White Label: Social Networking with commerce, or Ecommerce with Social networking

Tags: e-commerce, social-networking, saas, white-labelling

I've searched all over for a possible fit for providing basic commerce functionality (doc'd below) in a white label site, that is dirt simple to admin, and preferably supports auto creation of the site.  Super nice to have would be SaaS.

I'm hoping someone has done this before, has a suggestion, or can at least put me out of my misery.

I don't need anything fancy, just a way to light up a vendor site that:

*Mandatory:*

- White Label.  This includes any financial components
- can connect to a single shared catalog that is shared between many vendors
- pick the products they want for their site
- Has Social Networking abilities

*Nice to Have*

- has a blog per site (can be a logical
  separation)
- Has a CMS per site (Can be a logical separation)
- Auto creation

Also, SaaS is highly preferred.

The closest I've come is Drupal Commons on the DIY side, but I'd have to see if Commons will work with the existing modules for commerce.  Ning is a good example of what I'm trying to do.

DIY, SaaS, whatever, what I really need is some way to provide the above either through process (e.g. Drupal + Aegir) or though a paid service.  Custom coding is a last resort for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Wordpress 3 multisite with a combination of some plugins from WPMUDev.org... specifically for a basic setup:

Marketpress (Ecommerce) & Supporter (A Pseudo SAAS plugin)

and for good measure i would add some extras like google analytics, WPMU SEO, Mailchimp Integration, ect.

Ive got a pretty complex version of this currently built that i've setup to be easily customizable and i can fork to new "networks/domains" for niche markets and runs on an NGINX server on the Rackspace cloud. Users get subdomains and Every User can map their own domain. Super fast. Super easy to manage and completely able to whitelabel the backend. I develop these types of systems routinely for clients  and have reasonable dev rates if you need any help in this area.